# Checking if value exists in SQL and if not returning another row

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a MySQL SQL query that selects products and the text translations:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select * from products) p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM translations) t
ON t.id = p.product_id
```

This grabs the products from the database. However it grabs all the available translations. I just want to get the translations in the current language. So i can use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select * from products) p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM translations WHERE lang = 'en') t
ON t.id = p.product_id
```

This works as intended, however not all products have a translation for every language. What I ultimately want to do is specify a language and if there is no given translation then return whatever other translations we have. Can this be done in SQL or am i going to need to iterate through the results in PHP?

Comment: How will you decide which other translation to return?

Comment: Alex, until we know how to handle the case where `t.lang <> 'en'` the question is unanswerable.

Comment: I would choose whichever translation has the lowest id on the translation table (i.e. the oldest translation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a 'default' language translation for each product, and give it code `'zz'` then the following will work. There must be a `'zz'` translation for every product.

(This took me literally an hour, but I've learned a lot in the process - great question!).

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN translations t
ON (p.id == t.product_id
    AND (t.lang == 'en'
         OR (t.lang == 'zz' AND
             'en' NOT IN
             (SELECT `lang` FROM translations t2 WHERE t2.product_id == p.id)
            )
        )
   );
```

Sorry if it's not efficient. You'll need to try it out and see.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to add another LEFT JOIN that pulls the first translation available in any language for that product id.  Then use `COALESCE` statement to use the secondary translation if the first translation (in the desired language) is not available:

```
SELECT
    p.product_id,
    COALESCE(t.lang, t2.lang),
    COALESCE(t.translation, t2.translation)
FROM (select * from products) p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM translations WHERE lang = @lang) t
    ON t.id = product_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM translations
    WHERE lang = (SELECT min(lang) FROM translations
        WHERE t3.id = t2.id))
    t2 ON t2.id = p.product_id;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlize.com/46Q73VJW24